# Python text adv game - import error (can't go back to "main" menu)

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, importerror, python-import

So I've been building this little game for few days now as a little newbie exercise. I will include only two modules that I think are relevant, if I should include more just tell me and I'll put them in pastebin.

Here's the catch. My game starts from terminal by launching the script **start.py**. For user input I've created another module called **prompt.py** so I don't have to repeat the code. But I have run into a problem. When I'm calling function "load_menu" from **prompt.py** I want to be able to go back to main screen by entering 0 (function "splash_screen" in **start.py**). So if I want to replace line 53 in **prompt.py** (in function "load_menu")and put there `start.splash_screen()` instead I can't. Because when I put `import start` in the beginning of **prompt.py** I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 3, in <module>
    import player
  File "/Volumes/DATA HD/Dropbox/Python/ex45/player.py", line 3, in <module>
    import prompt
  File "/Volumes/DATA HD/Dropbox/Python/ex45/prompt.py", line 7, in <module>
    import start
  File "/Volumes/DATA HD/Dropbox/Python/ex45/start.py", line 61, in <module>
    splash_screen()
  File "/Volumes/DATA HD/Dropbox/Python/ex45/start.py", line 22, in splash_screen
    action = prompt.menu()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'menu'
```

There is something wrong and I don't know what it is. Is the module **start** reserved for something else in Python?

Here is **start.py**

```
import sys
import custom_error
import player
import handler
import prompt
import splashscreen
import game


def splash_screen():
    print chr(27) + "[2J"
    splashscreen.intro()
    print "*" * 80
    print "***** Welcome to ZOMBIE ADVENTURE *****"
    print "*" * 80
    print "\nSelect option:"
    print "1. Start a new game"
    print "2. Load existing game"
    print "3. Quit"

    while True:
        action = prompt.menu()

        if action == 1:
            create_player = player.CreateNewPlayer()
            create_player_args = create_player.generate()
            the_player = player.Player(*create_player_args)

            print "\nYour name is %s and you're %d old." % (the_player.name, the_player.age)
            print "It is %s that you're a man." % str(the_player.male).lower()
            print "Your maximum health is %d hitpoints." % the_player.hitpoints

            print "\n1. Continue to game"
            print "2. Back to main menu"
            action = prompt.menu()


            if action == 1:
                prompt.game_help()
                custom_error.errortype(4)
                print chr(27) + "[2J"

                a_game = game.Engine(the_player, 'Apartment')
                a_game.move()

            elif action == 2:
                handler.load()
            else:
                custom_error.errortype(3)
                custom_error.errortype(2)
                splash_screen()
                # a_game = game.Engine()
                # a_game.launch_game(the_player)
        elif action == 2:
            handler.load()
        elif action == 3:
            splash_screen()
        else:
            custom_error.errortype(0)

splash_screen()
```

And here is **prompt.py**

```
import handler
import sys
import hint
import game
import player
import custom_error
import start


def standard(the_player):

    while True:

        user_input = str(raw_input("> ")).lower()

        if user_input == "hint":
            print "hint"
            # ziskej soucasnou polohu a pak hint.hints.get(poloha)
        elif user_input == "save":
            handler.save(the_player)
            # ziskej soucasnou polohu a pak game.save(poloha)
        elif user_input == "inventory" or user_input == "inv":
            print the_player.inventory.keys()
        elif user_input == "char":
            print "\n---", the_player.name, "---"
            print "Age:", the_player.age
            print "Is male:", the_player.male
            print "Hitpoints:", the_player.hitpoints
            print "Current location:", the_player.location, "\n"
        elif user_input == "help":
            game_help()
        elif user_input == "quit":
            exit(1)
        else:
            return user_input


def menu():

    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(raw_input("\nType a number > "))
            return user_input
        except ValueError:
            custom_error.errortype(1)

def load_menu():

        while True:
            try:
                user_input = int(raw_input("\nType a number or type 0 to QUIT > "))

                if user_input == 0:
                    exit(1)
                else:
                    return user_input
            except ValueError:
                custom_error.errortype(1)



def load_game():

    while True:
        try:
            user_input = str(raw_input("\nLoad this character? Y/N > ")).lower()

            if user_input == "y" or user_input == "n":
                return user_input
            else:
                print "Please type in 'Y' or 'N' only."
        except ValueError:
            custom_error.errortype(3)

def game_help():

    print "\n"
    print "-" * 80
    print "Type HELP anytime to display this message."
    print "-" * 80
    print "Type these commands anytime to perform actions:"
    print " * HINT: If you're stuck, you can get little help."
    print " * SAVE: Save your progress."
    print " * INV: Will display contents of your inventory."
    print " * CHAR: Shows character stats."
    print " * QUIT: Quit game without saving (to save"
    print "         use the appropriate command.)"
```

I have also included the rest of the files:

- [game.py](http://pastebin.com/K2NerZMa)
- [player.py](http://pastebin.com/BaAxebJa)
- [custom_error.py](http://pastebin.com/ukaZtYKx)
- [splashscreen.py](http://pastebin.com/XnmFhXVS)
- [handler.py](http://pastebin.com/V4QJXzea)
- [apartment.py](http://pastebin.com/8vX14KmX)
- [curling_street.py](http://pastebin.com/BT61rMGm)

Comment: Can you post the full project on github, bitbucket, or something similar? See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the term is reserved.

Are you missing `__init__.py` in your project? It's difficult to know without the structure.

Another possibility is maybe you are doing a circular import in a few places - it looks to me like I see it in prompt.py and start.py. They import each other. While it's possible to do some tricks, don't do that for something you argue you want simple. Instead, refactor.

I created a test project with only start.py and prompt.py, along with `__init__.py` for the package, and that confirms nothing is reserved, so at the very least, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: OK, I'm still very new and this so I'm probably doing it wrong (in fact, this is my first project where I'm using several py files).

Yes, I am missing `__init__.py`. Haven't heard of it so I will need to look it up.

Also, I always thought that I need to import every .py file that contains a function or class that I'm using in any current file.

Comment: See - http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module

Comment: Basically, I am saying if you have modules A and B, either A imports B or B imports A. This is the most pragmatic and python way to solve the issue. In other words, B cannot import A when A also imports B. The above link goes into further detail. Simply move your code around.

Regarding __init__.py, just place it in the directory where you defined your python package. So if everything were under a folder "mygame", put __init__.py as a blank file there. There are various reasons you might use code in this file, but normally I feel it's not needed and even a bad idea in most cases.

Comment: One last comment to address your concerns - regarding imports, you do need to import what you use. You can import a module or a specific function from a module (import start vs from start import splash_screen).

Comment: I'm sorry I can't still figure it out. I've tried creating import.py file and put those imports there but when I reference it in prompt.py I still get the same error.

Comment: I wouldn't call anything import.py, bad idea. But in general I think you should simplify. Just reduce the code to bare print statements in a project that has only what you need. In general, you really need to reorganize your code. Put things that are functionally grouped together (classes and methods) into modules, then import them unidirectionally. For example, you might have your game import your menus, but not your menu import your games. It's pretty clear to me looking at your code the issue is circular imports. You have architecture issues, but that's out scope in this discussion.